# Salesforce Screen flow Datatable

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

The source collection in the data table of screen flow can hold record collection. Is it possible to show data from multiple sources like wrapper class?

I want to show the list of Contacts along with their distance from the given location. User enters a range from screen flow, and the invocable apex should return the list of contact and their distance within the given range.
I have created invocable method and debug is showing the expected result, but I need to show the data in the datatable of screen flow.

Thanks